# Possible to only query a sub document in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my test collection

```
[
  {
    "_id": "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6c",
    "text": "outter",
    "username": "test1",
    "address": [
      {
        "text": "inner",
        "username": "test2",
        "_id": "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6e"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

If I do

```
t1 = await doc.find({}, 'text').exec();
console.log(JSON.stringify(t1, null, 2));
```

I get

```
[
  {
    "_id": "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6c",
    "text": "outter"
  }
]
```

So here it finds the parent `text`.

**Question**

How do I get Mongoose to query the sub document instead of the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can project the sub document(s) like this:

```
t1 = await doc.find({}, {'address.text':1}).exec();
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wJEQ7d92AxV)

Comment: What does the `:1` mean?

Comment: That you want to get this field back inside the result

Comment: And `-1` means "don't include"?

Comment: `0` means "don't include"

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the sub document, not even the _id of the parent:

```
await doc.find(
  {},
  {
    _id: 0,
    'address.text': 1
  }
).exec();`
```